# Set checkbox label's text in modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I have a modal for creating new post. I want to allow the user to select departments for sharing so I'm using checkboxes for choosing the audience.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="createNewPostModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Post</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <form method="post" id="createNewPostForm">
                        <textarea rows="3" name="text" placeholder="Write something..."></textarea>
                        <div>
                            <p>Select audience to share</p>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="depACheckBox">
                                <label id="depACheckBoxLabel" for="depACheckBox"></label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="depBCheckBox" >
                                <label id="depBCheckBoxLabel" for="depBCheckBox"></label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="depCCheckBox">
                                <label id="depCCheckBoxLabel" for="CheckBox"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return createNewPost(this.parentNode);" id="createNewPostButton" data-dismiss="modal">Share</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Different users have different departments to be shown and they are saved in mongoDB user document. I need to set the labels of the checkboxes on loading the modal.

I'm getting user's document on page load, so my attempt inside the getUser function:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#createNewPostModal").on('load', function(){
            document.getElementById('depACheckBoxLabel').innerText = window.user.depA.name;
            document.getElementById('depBCheckBoxLabel').innerText = window.user.depB.name;
            document.getElementById('depCCheckBoxLabel').innerText = window.user.depC.name;
        });
    });
```

I tried innerHTML as well but label still remains empty. How do I set the label text as or after the modal is shown?

Comment: Are those id used anywhere else in the document? For example, do you have multiple instances of this modal?

Comment: I need this in many pages so I put it in top nav bar. I'm using ejs framework and the nav bar is populated with links to this modal, search and logout by a function in the footer.ejs file that checks whether user is logged in or not. So almost all pages have footer included and the links to the modal but the modal itself exists at only one place, inside footer.ejs file. The ids are not anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `onload` on anything other than `window` it will have no effect.

If you want to check for the `#createNewPostModal` div before running your function you can do something like the below example:

```js
$(document).ready(checkModal);

function checkModal () {
  if($('#createNewPostModal').is(':visible')){ //if the container is visible on the page
    document.getElementById('depACheckBoxLabel').innerHTML = "this";
    document.getElementById('depBCheckBoxLabel').innerHTML = "works";
    document.getElementById('depCCheckBoxLabel').innerHTML = "now";
  } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="createNewPostModal">
  <p>Select audience to share</p>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="depACheckBox">
    <label id="depACheckBoxLabel" for="depACheckBox"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="depBCheckBox">
    <label id="depBCheckBoxLabel" for="depBCheckBox"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="depCCheckBox">
    <label id="depCCheckBoxLabel" for="CheckBox"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Feel free to adjust the check for `:visible` to something that suits your needs when referring to that container.

---

Additionally, as requested in your comment, if you want to call this function `onclick` you can do this:

```js
$('button').click(checkModal);

function checkModal () {
  if($('#createNewPostModal').is(':visible')){ //if the container is visible on the page
    document.getElementById('depACheckBoxLabel').innerHTML = "this";
    document.getElementById('depBCheckBoxLabel').innerHTML = "works";
    document.getElementById('depCCheckBoxLabel').innerHTML = "now";
  } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="createNewPostModal">
  <p>Select audience to share</p>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="depACheckBox">
    <label id="depACheckBoxLabel" for="depACheckBox"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="depBCheckBox">
    <label id="depBCheckBoxLabel" for="depBCheckBox"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="depCCheckBox">
    <label id="depCCheckBoxLabel" for="CheckBox"></label>
  </div>
</div>


<button onclick="checkModal()">Click</button>
```

Just swap `button` for whatever element you want to trigger the function from.

---

Lastly, if it isn't necessary to wait for the `#createNewPostModal` div to load then just call your function like this and it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() { document.getElementById('depACheckBoxLabel').innerHTML = window.user.depA.name; document.getElementById('depBCheckBoxLabel').innerHTML = window.user.depB.name; document.getElementById('depCCheckBoxLabel').innerHTML = window.user.depC.name; });
```

Comment: I don't know why but this didn't work for me. Is there a way I can call the function when the link is clicked? I tried to add id to the a tag that brings up the modal and run the function onclick but that broke the navbar for some reason. I don't understand what's going on. I'm calling another function inside getUser to populate sidenav with department names and it works, so the data is there but it's not working with this modal. Please help.